# C# default visibility of properites

Tags: c#-4.0

Is there a way to change the default visibility of properties and methods in C#? I'm writing code were pretty much everything needs to be public and the default for properties and methods is private and constantly typing public is getting really old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change these defaults. They are defined in the language spec.

Properties being private/internal by default is a design decision made by the C# team, there is no way to globally override it.

If you are using visual studio, you can use the [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b.aspx) for properties (`prop`, `propg` and `propfull`). This can ease the pain of repeatedly typing in property code and will product the right syntax every time.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet tip. I'm a little new to visual studio so the code snippet stuff will come in handy.

Comment: @davidk01 - don't limit yourself to the built in ones, you can create your own!

Answer (score 2):

No, It's not possible to the change the default visibility of properties and methods in C#, since they are language dependents(ie language characteristics) , the user or programmers has no rights to change these things.